# reactjs render() not triggered after promise resolves this.setState is re-assigned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, setstate

I have a function below which sets an InitialState and then makes an api call with componentWillMount and fetchData to assign the data this.state. However when this.setState() is done the render function does not triggered with the new this.state data my function is below:

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      city: '',
      weather: '',
      temperature: 0,
      humidity: 0,
      wind: 0,
    }
  },
  fetchData: function() {
    apiHelpers.getCityInfo()
    .then(function (response){
      this.setState({ data: response
      })
    }.bind(this))
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.fetchData();
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <Cities data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: how did you know that render not triggered? maybe it's triggered but renders same result?

Comment: Hi, well I inserted a console.log in fetchData and in render and the promise resolves, setState is executed however the render method doesn't re-run and update with the new this.state values

Comment: Well, answer should help you then. `componentWillMount` is very rare used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `data` on initial state. Change your code as-

```
fetchData: function() {
    apiHelpers.getCityInfo()
     .then(function (response){
      this.setState({
          city: response.city,
          weather: response.weather,
          temperature: response.temperature,
          humidity: response.humidity,
          wind: response.wind,
       })
    }.bind(this))
  },
```

expecting your api response contain object as city, weather, ... so on..

Answer (score 0):

As per the react docs

`componentWillMount` is Invoked once, both on the `client and server`, immediately before the initial rendering occurs. If you call setState within this method, `render()` will see the updated state and will be executed only `once` despite the state change.

To solve this issue, instead of `componentWillMount` use `componentDidMount`. Since you are updating the response in state variable `data`, define it first and then no need of defining the other state variables just pass data on to the `child component` and update the state as you are doing now.

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: ''
    }
  },
  fetchData: function() {
    apiHelpers.getCityInfo()
    .then(function (response){
      this.setState({ data: response
      })
    }.bind(this))
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.fetchData();
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <Cities data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, componentDidMount() doesn't run the fetchData function at all.

Comment: Did you try and console.log() into the fetchData function and see if it runs

Comment: Hi yes, co componentDidMount and componentWillMount are not running the fetchData function

Comment: Is it not running the fetchdata or apihelpers.getcityinfo can you check

Comment: it is running fetchData and apihelpers, however the render() runs before the apiHelpers promise is resolved, once the promise is resolved the render() does not run again

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I can see that your issue is resolved but edited the answer just to let you know of a more efficient way to tackle the problem than the other answer